# How to remove previously added permissions with a SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, permissions, designer-workflow, impersonation

I recently created a SharePoint library, and added a `PeoplePicker` field.  I then went into SPD and created a 2010 workflow, and created:

if PeoplePicker field not empty, use impersonate function to add `Read` access for current item

This works great. (Well, only when I only have 1 person in the field. As soon as I add an additional person to the field, the workflow fails. But that's another problem for another day).

What I need to do next is, if I remove someone from the `PeoplePicker` field, I want to be able to write a workflow to remove the person's permission from that file.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: As I see it, you could make this work by creating a OnChange workflow, which would reset the item permissions to inherit from parents, and add again Read access to user in the PeoplePicker field.
Note: This will not work as expected if you have unique permissions for the item though...

Comment: @douvillema I would mark your comment as the correct answer

Comment: There is the "remove" permissions action that works fine.  But I couldn't actually get that to work, it kept completing the workflow, but didn't actually remove the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by creating a workflow which execute `OnItemCreation` in SPD.

With a 2010 workflow, use an `Impersonation Step` and simply use the `Inherit List Item Parent Permissions` action, and add again the permissions like you did in the first workflow.

---

### 2013 Workflow

I'm not sure if you can do the same with a 2013 workflow. AFAIK, there's no such action for a 2010 workflow, but you may be able to do it via Rest API.

---

**Tip**: You could actually edit your 1st workflow to add these steps instead, avoiding to have multiple workflows for one action.